# What was governor Nix's motive to keep the Monitor on?

Tags: plot-explanation, tomorrowland

What was governor Nix's motive to keep the Monitor on in *Tomorrowland*? I know he said:

> Shutting it down is impossible. There is no off.

But at least he could blow it up, just like what Frank did. So it seems that the governor didn't want to shut it down, but the motive wasn't mentioned through the film.

In his last speech about why he started to send signals in the first place, I couldn't find any reason for him to keep going on; he had seen Earth and mankind's future and decided to show them what will happen if they continue their current activities. As a result, he saw that humans are acting in the opposite direction he thought. So what was his motive to keep sending those negative signals?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to think that once Nix discovered humanity's reaction to the idea of their demise (being that they amplified their "efforts" towards it), he should have tried to shut it down, like Frank did. But that's not what Nix intends, as clarified in that scene. When he says that line about shutting it down, that was just an act before Frank got onto his game. **He never intended to shut it down.**

He *knows* that the signal causes humanity to further their demise. But **he blames the humans, *not* the monitor**. In his opinion the signal only *amplifies* the humans' inherent urge for chaos and destruction. In contrast to Frank and Casey **he doesn't *believe* in humanity.**

We can even go further than that. *His* reaction to what the monitor caused was as much a self-fulfilling prophecy as the monitor's signal itself. I would postulate that Nix never had much respect for the rest of humanity to begin with and when he showed them the visions from the monitor it only confirmed his prejudice against them when they *didn't* understand its message. You could even say the signal served as an **excuse for Nix to finally drop all concerns about humanity**, since, well, they bring it upon themselves anyway, right? It's not like he didn't *"try"* to help them and show them the errors in their way, right?

So once he learned, in his opinion, that humanity is unsalvageable, **there was no point for him to shut the signal down.** If they want to destroy themselves, then just let them do it and get it over with. He stopped caring about the humans and the monitor "confirmed" his actions. For Nix the **signal basically just gave him the power *and* the authority to make humanity fulfill what he thought to be its destiny anyway**. He long lost his hope for humanity, if there ever was some is another question, though.